# Should e-commerce customers have the possibility to haggle?

Tags: e-commerce, pricing, customer-experience

More and more webshops use obvious and sometimes seemingly arbitrary user data to adjust the prices for services or products that they ask of them. That means, for instance, the price may be higher if the customer is using an Apple product or mobile device to access the website or it may be lower if tracking cookies show that the user has visited competing stores or price comparison sites that would allow them to find a lower offer.

Such dynamic prices are actually very common in bazars and other physical markets, or used to be at least, but the customer would a) usually know about this and b) be able to offer a lower amount, i.e. *haggling* or *bargaining*. Years ago, Ebay has introduced the option for sellers to grant prospective buyers the possibility to suggest a price they would be willing to pay, which the merchant can then accept, refuse or propose an alternative for ([“Best Offer”](http://pages.ebay.com/help/buy/best-offer.html) or [private offer](http://pages.ebay.com/help/sell/private_offer.html)); this may go on for several rounds, each with a timeout window of two days.

Is there any UX research from studies or actual implementations that indicates whether retail users (B2C), especially in fashion and electronics segments, feel more empowered by such negotiation possibilities for either individual items or the whole shopping basket/cart? In other words, does it effectively counter the feeling of being ripped off by dynamic prices?

If there is such research, does it also show whether customers would accept or even expect a delay in the buying process, because a human would (seemingly) have to review the offer?

I also like to think that more dynamic haggling could effectively replace coupon codes etc.

Comment: We really can't predict what will happen, until we see it in reality. I don't know if there is relevant research about that.

Comment: Although *very* interesting, this does seem like speculation that can only result in opinion based answers.

Comment: Although I’m afraid that @AndrewMartin has a point, I sincerely hope that there’s someone around here who does have actual experience or research which Kristiyan Lukanov and I acknowledge to lack.

Comment: I think this is very product specific. There is no general rule. Supermarkets reduce the price of their rapid perishables before closing because they won't be able to sell them tomorrow. In contrast, iPhones stay at their current price until the new model is released. Car models get reductions late in their model life, but command a premium earlier in their life.

Comment: So any discussion of this must require a deep consideration of the product category, its regional target market, and the time/timings and service expectations of the consumer, too.

Comment: Can you give some example products in your scenario, or something similar?

Comment: @Confused I was mostly thinking about fashion/clothing on the one hand and computer hardware/electronic appliances on the other, but also about customizable general-purpose webshop software.

Comment: Haggling on the web will be an interesting thing to have on commerce sites targeting people who really wants see more options (eg: Alibaba). But in real life haggling is so real time and it will be a challenge to bring the experience to the web. But I really the concept you said about replacing coupon codes with an option to bargain the price.

Comment: Thinking of a simple scenario product 'X' which is listed on Amazon cost Rs.1000 and a customer is going to buy it. Now before adding to the cart he has the option to haggle so that he can try to buy it at a discounted price. Now from the seller perspective, they are fine to sell X on a discount range of Rs.900-Rs.1000.  Now in the haggling screen, we provide a textbox to enter the price suggestion from the customer to enter his price suggestion and submit it to the server for validation.

Comment: So now the customer enter Rs.800 and submit for validation. During validation, it checks whether the price suggestion (R.800) by the customer falling in between the discount range(Rs.900-Rs.1000) provided by the seller. Now based on some business rule response back with a new reduced price Rs.990 also saying we can't accept Rs.800 but do you wish to buy it at Rs.990? Now the user can continue haggling or accept the price or cancel the product. The business rules can accompany the user stats also to give good deals based on users.

Comment: And haggling continues and at on point, the rule can stop decreasing the price and fix a final price and the user can continue to buy it or cancel. This is just a vague thought but What do you think about this flow?